# Select dynamic couples of lines in SQL (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

My objective is to make dynamic group of lines (of product by TYPE & COLOR in fact)

I don't know if it's possible just with one select query.

But : I want to create group of lines (A PRODUCT is a TYPE and a COLOR) as per the number_per_group column and I want to do this grouping depending on the date order (Order By DATE)

A single product with a NB_PER_GROUP number 2 is exclude from the final result.

```
Table :

-----------------------------------------------
NUM |  TYPE |   COLOR  | NB_PER_GROUP   | DATE
-----------------------------------------------
0   |  1    |   1      |    2           |  ...
1   |  1    |   1      |    2           |
2   |  1    |   2      |    2           |
3   |  1    |   2      |    2           |
4   |  1    |   1      |    2           |
5   |  1    |   1      |    2           |
6   |  4    |   1      |    3           |
7   |  1    |   1      |    2           |
8   |  4    |   1      |    3           |
9   |  4    |   1      |    3           |
10  |  5    |   1      |    2           |


Results :

------------------------
GROUP_NUMBER   |  NUM  | 
------------------------
0              |   0   |
0              |   1   |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1              |   2   |
1              |   3   |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2              |   4   |
2              |   5   |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
3              |   6   |
3              |   8   |
3              |   9   |
```

If you have another way to solve this problem, I will accept it.

Comment: What is difference between `GROUP = 0` and `GROUP = 2`?

Comment: The Group 2 is the 2nd group of the product (1,1). There are multiples groups for a same product : Group 0 : 1st group (1,1) , Group 2 : 2nd group (1,1).

Comment: This looks like something you should do in your application layer, iterating over the result of a query with `ORDER BY`. There result of an SQL query is a _relation_ and your desired output is not at all relation-like.

Comment: So we are agree, it's impossible to have this result only with SQL query. (without PL/SQL)

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
select max(gn.group_number) group_number, ip.num
from products ip
join (
    select date, type, color, row_number() over (order by date) - 1 group_number
    from (
        select op.num, op.type, op.color, op.nb_per_group, op.date, (row_number() over (partition by op.type, op.color order by op.date) - 1) % nb_per_group group_order
        from products op
    ) sq
    where sq.group_order = 0
) gn
 on ip.type = gn.type
and ip.color = gn.color
and ip.date >= gn.date
group by ip.num
order by group_number, ip.num
```

This may only work if your nb_per_group values are the same for each combination of type and color.  It may also require unique dates, but that could probably be worked around if required.

The innermost subquery partitions the rows by type and color, orders them by date, then calculates the row numbers modulo nb_per_group; this forms a 0-based count for the group that resets to 0 each time nb_per_group is exceeded.

The next-level subquery finds all of the 0 values we mapped in the lower subquery and assigns group numbers to them.

Finally, the outermost query ties each row in the products table to a group number, calculated as the highest group number that split off before this product's date.